# Remix Using Complex Components

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, remix.run

Trying to include AG Grid  https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/ in a Remix project but it is not rendering.

No errors in terminal console or web console, In react project this works fine. So something with remix and complex components. Have tried wrapping in ClientOnly from remix-utils but no difference.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import{ClientOnly } from 'remix-utils';

export default function Grid() {
 const [rowData] = useState([
    {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
    {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
    {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
]);

const [columnDefs] = useState([
    { field: 'make' },
    { field: 'model' },
    { field: 'price' }
])

return (
    <ClientOnly>
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height: 400, width: 600}}>
        <AgGridReact
            rowData={rowData}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}>
        </AgGridReact>
    </div>
    </ClientOnly>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the error. It was missing the

```
<Scripts />
```

tag in the root.tsx